# PHP Insert Values if they are set

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

Looking for a little guidance as I don't know how to echo all my set options into an [asana](/questions/tagged/asana) request. So I have an array from a user submitted form:

```
Array
(
[_wpcf7] => 5
[_wpcf7_version] => 4.1.2
[_wpcf7_locale] => en_US
[_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f5-o1
[_wpnonce] => 1531937d4e
[your-name] => TEST
[your-email] => test@test.com
[title] => test
[Description] => test
[venues] => Dragonfly
[duedate] => 2015-04-11
[options] => Array
    (
        [0] => Print Business Card (3.5x2)
        [1] => Google Ads Package
        [2] => Print Ticket (1.5x5.5)
        [3] => Print Magazine Ad (8x10.75)
    )

[_wpcf7_is_ajax_call] => 1
[upload] => ditch_fridays_logo.png
)
```

From there I parse the array to grab the variables:

```
$submittedBy = $posted_data['your-name'];
$eMail = $posted_data['your-email'];
$projectTitle = $posted_data['title'];
$projectDescription = $posted_data['Description'];
$venue = $posted_data['venues'];
$deadline = $posted_data['duedate'];
$options = $posted_data['options'];
$upload = $posted_data['upload'];
```

And then I create the asana task

```
// First we create the task
$result = $asana->createTask(array(
    'workspace' => $workspaceId, // Workspace ID
    'name' => $projectTitle, // Name of task
    'assignee' => 'somewhere@somewhere.com', // Assign task to...
    'due_on' => $deadline,
    'notes' => 'Submitted By: ' . $submittedBy . "\n" . 'E-Mail: ' . $eMail . "\n\n" . '--------------------------------------------------' . "\n\n" . 'Task Name: ' . $projectTitle . "\n\n" . 'Description:  ' . $projectDescription . "\n\n" . 'Venue:  ' . $venue . "\n\n" . 'Deadline: ' . $deadline . "\n\n" . 'Attachments: http://inkentertainment.com/graphics/saved/' . $upload 
));
```

The problem is, I cant include the selected options in the notes part of the task creation. How would I go about including all the options ($posted_data['options']) only if the user has selected them? (on the form there is a list of about 10, but the users will select 2 or 3)

I hope I have been clear enough for you to understand, if not let me know and I will try and clarify

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = ( isset   ( $posted_data[ 'options' ] ) &&
             is_array( $posted_data[ 'options' ] ) ) ?
           $posted_data[ 'options' ] : array();
```

here you'll have an array with zero or more elements.

If you need a string you may then use `implode`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

ex: `$options = implode( ', ', $options );`